# Get collection with own data and secified vars from sub collection in eloquent

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

First of all, sorry when the question description does not describe my question very well but i have no idea how to form my question better in one line. Suggestions are welcome..

**Background info**

- Laravel 5.6.x
- I defined my objects as eloquent models
- Using migrations to create the database

**Background info about the application**

I have an application where a `Game` object has a one-to-many relation with `Player` objects. The `Game` object contains all game details, the `Player` object contains all details of an individual player.

Players gets invited for a game and can accept of deny this. This info is saved in the player themselves as the player is unique per game.

Now i want to create an overview of all games. One of the things in the overview are the amount of *accepted players*, the *invited players* and their *id's*.

To get all games, i use `$games = Game::all();` what gives me an array with all games (without players). I was able to add the players to the array by doing:

```
foreach ($game as $singleGame){
   $singleGame->players
}
```

After that my $games array contains all games with a subcollection per game with its players. This is almost what i need, but the subcollection contains to many details about the player, e.g. the hand cards the player has.

**The question**
Is there a simple way to just add the `invite_status` and `player_id` value of each player to the game its sub-collection instead of all the players vars?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
$games = Game::with(['players' => function( $query){
    $query->select('invite_status', 'player_id');
}])->get();
```

Using a loop to get the players of each game will make a query for each one, which is very bad. Using `with()` would load all of them with one query and specifying which fields you need with a `select()`.

Comment: Seems to be what i need... unfortunately the query does not work well as the players added to the individual games are always 0 with the querry above. I already checked the var names in the player object but these are correct. When i comment out the ` $query->select('invite_status', 'player_id');` it does include the players but with all vars. And i agree that query just 1 time is much better but had no idea how to do as beginner with Laravel/Eloquent.

Comment: @RoDo, include in `$query->select('invite_status', 'player_id');` the column which is the relation to your game, probably `game_id` or something like that.

Comment: You can shorten it: `Game::with('players:invite_status,player_id,game_id')->get();`

Comment: Thanks, both of you. With adding the relation id (`game_id` indeed) it works perfect! Also the short method is very usefull but its good to have also the full query as it gives an better idea about how to build a query.